# Why install Android LatinIME gets Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: android, sdk, apk, android-virtual-device

I had download and compiled the source code from GIT, and also successfully runs the emulator compiled along with the code.

Then I managed to use `mmm android/packages/inputmethods/LationIME`  to complie the LatinIME,
and use `adb install -r android/out/target/product/generic/system/app/LatinIME.apk` and it installed well.

But this only works with the AVD I compiled myself, when I tried to install the `LatinIME.apk` copied form `android/out/target/product/generic/system/app/` to another emulator or a real phone by the same command: `adb install -r LatinIME.apk`, I get the message:

`165 KB/s (568039 bytes in 3.343s)

     pkg: /data/local/tmp/LatinIME.apk

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]`

I've Googled a lot and tried what they had say:

- Add the line `<uses-sdk android:MinSdkVersion="3">` in the file `LatinIME/AndroidManifest.xml'
- Modify the `android/build/core/version_defaults.mk`, change the line `DEFAULT_APP_TARGET_SDK := $(PLATFORM_SDK_VERSION)` to `DEFAULT_APP_TARGET_SDK := 8`
- I even re-downloaded the source code, the first time I downloaded was the default latest version with API level 10, the second time I download the code of API level 9, both can't complie an pak that can be installed in other emulators on API level 8 or 9 or 10.

I thought it might because that the SDK I complied is `AOSP` version so it can't be installed in 
official released SDK? I'm not very clear with the difference.

Anyone having the source code please try `mmm android/packages/inputmethods/LationIME` and see if the generated apk can be installed in official SDK version?

Comment: Can i just download the source form https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME in order to compile the LatinIME.apk?

Comment: @CelinHC You can try it out because this question is long ago, maybe the latset verison is able to be compiled alone, but the old version I know  will need the whole environment to compile because it relied on some NDK parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I'm answering my own question again, I can't understand why my questions always rarely answered.

However I searched the whole Internet and can find a answer, but in luck I saw this:

[version_defaults.mk of API Key 7](http://code.google.com/p/pdn-slatedroid/source/browse/trunk/eclair/build/core/version_defaults.mk?r=4)

I simply replaced the `android/build/core/version_defaults.mk` in my downloaded code tree and re-compiled the module, and it worked!

Thought I don't know if it will work all modules in the source code, but however my IME works good.

Comment: Your question are not the usual ones :) Never done what you have tried here... but it is good to read a question other than "listview doesn't update" or "help me and give the code..." :D

Comment: It's because the original version_defaults.mk limited the apks compiled form the AOSP tree, making them cannot be installed in any released SDK versions, saying that may have some differences in dependency since the AOSP is updating all the time.

Comment: @Aloong I get that error, but when I decompile final APK, there is no min/target attribute!